# Laravel: Auth error after upgrade 5.1 -> 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I've been handed an old Laravel application, which was running v5.1 and have used Shift to upgrade it through the Laravel v9.

The whole app is behind a login ~ and on submit of the login form (correct or fail), it returns:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php on line 421 and exactly 3 expected
```

and the trace ends in `app  / Providers / AppServiceProvider.php: 37`, line 37 being `function ($sql, $bindings, $time)`

```
....
error_reporting(0);

        // public function boot(Guard $auth) {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) use ($auth) {
            if ($auth->user()) {
                // get the current user
                $currentUser = $auth->user();
                Log::info('Executed by '.$currentUser->email);
                // pass the data to the view
                $view->with('currentUser', $currentUser);
            }
        });

        DB::listen(
            function ($sql, $bindings, $time) {
                $a = print_r($sql, 1);
                $b = print_r($bindings, 1);
                $logmessage = $a;
                if (! empty($b)) {
                    $logmessage .= ' : '.$b;
                }
                Log::info($logmessage);
            }
        );
...
```

During the Shift process, re. the login/auth process it noted the following:

> Laravel 5.3 split the Auth/AuthController.php into the Auth/LoginController.php and the Auth/RegisterController.php. Since yours appears to be customized, Shift did not remove it. You should compare your Auth/AuthController.php with the newly added controllers and merge your changes accordingly.

and

> If you are using Authentication, you should upgrade any routes using AuthController and PasswordController to use the new authentication controllers. Laravel recommends using the Auth::routes() which registers the proper routes for the new authentication controllers. This method also registers a POST route for /logout instead of a GET route.

but the highlighted error line seems related to the database connection...

A quick sanity check of database connection:

```
  try {
        \DB::connection()->getPDO();
        echo \DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'None';
    }
```

returns the correct database connection, as expected.

I'm not a Laravel-specific dev so trying to muddle my way through and no doubt need to provide more debugging info here, so just let me know what else would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Laravel Shift is a a payable service, why dont you contact their support for your issue ?

Comment: @N69S I don't think it's an issue caused by Shift itself but something I need to fix myself following a merge problem (as per the two notes Shift reported, in the original post).

Comment: post those controllers mentioned as well as the `AppServiceProdiver` and `AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: only 1 argument is passed to that closure as the error says ... https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#listening-for-query-events

Comment: Go back to the shift from (hopefully) 5.2 to 5.3, meaning it did your shifts version by version. Go back to the error log and be prepared to copy paste a huge part of the laravel.log (entire stacktrace). Routes in Laravel are located in /routes/web.php see if you can make that change correctly. Fix the app in version 5.3 and then shift to... let's say Laravel 6. Make sure your app keeps working the entire time after a shift

Answer (score 0):

After chatting to the helpful team at Shift, we deduced it was caused by the DB logging.

We removed that block and it resolved everything.

> The issue is probably just a signature mismatch. But either way, you probably don’t want that kind of code in production. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`DB::listen`'s signature has changed to a single argument that contains your three arguments as properties, so you'll need to adjust that call to fit if you still want to log SQL queries.

<sup>(I'd suggest replacing with https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar or https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/telescope for this purpose, though.)</sup>

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database

```
use Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted;

DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) {
    // $query->sql;
    // $query->bindings;
    // $query->time;
});
```